# What is the origin of "area51"?

Tags: discussion, area-51

This tag is about discussion on creating new StackExchange sites. Why is this tag named `area51`. Does it have anything to do with the US Air Force Facility in Nevada? How did the tag name originate for its use in StackExchange?

Comment: Maybe they got some art, decided it was cool, wanted to use it somewhere and chose the name from that?

Comment: @RobertLongson: What art? The aliens as per the FAQ?

Comment: So in essence, according to StackExchange, Area 51 is a location where new site proposals like StackOverflow are considered as aliens and are then discussed to be whether or not to be welcomed by StackExchange world. Right @RobertLongson?

Comment: Seems a pretty reasonable interpretation, yes.

Answer (score 3):

The [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) says

> We like the little aliens.

The idea that aliens are associated with the US area 51 facility is part of popular culture. It's a secret place for the US military so they must be hiding something and that something must be aliens say the conspiracy theorists. The notion is popularised by many films and TV series including [Independence Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_%281996_film%29) and [The X files](http://x-files.wikia.com/wiki/Area_51)

Comment: What is that supposed to mean? Could you expand on that?

Comment: I see. But what do aliens have to do with the US Air Force Facility?

Comment: Reading the wiki article may be of help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_51

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly widely accepted by the scientific community that following the [Roswell Incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roswell_UFO_incident) the United State government had in their possession an alien UFO that was transported to Area 51. The craft was reverse-engineered and technologies discovered led to the development of stealth fighters, WiFi and Miracle Whip.

What is lesser known is that from that and later contact several alien species were captured alive and used as part of a alien hybridization plan in an attempt to create a new breed of [super soldier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersoldier). From some [highly classified documents](http://alfa-omega720.blogspot.com.au/2015/01/las-sorprendentes-7-razas-alienginas.html) I found the following illustration that shows some of the most common species:

[image]

Rather than try to influence your beliefs I'd encourage you to open the [Meet the Team Building Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about/team) page in another browser for comparison. I will leave it to you to draw your own conclusions but I think the close connection between Stack Exchange and Area 51 will become obvious.